# PHP: Session not working

Tags: php, session

when user log's in at client, i am redirecting to server, ther i am setting session on user_id once his user_id and password are verified, i am redirecting back to client.
then, i am asking to fill profile info. if he want to fill the info by facebook, popup window appear which asks for permision to facebook api.

then  i want to store access token into  db.  for this i am redirecting to server with user_id , accesstoken and other info to server. there i am checking session to verify that he is same user.

but not working.
more details:

In server, i have two function, validate() and facebook(). In validate function, i am creating session. when i am going from validate function to facebook function and thr if if i echo session of 'user_id' it is printing. -------- but, when i go validate function to client site and then if came back to server/facebook it is not printing

Comment: you can always verify your data by putting `print_r($_SESSION);` at the bottom of your code to manually debug

Comment: add this to the top of your application: `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and then run again, I can be your sending some output before the `session_start()` causing session to to set the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the function `session_start()` ?

That will fix the problem most of the times.

Comment: yes. In server,  i have two function, validate() and facebook(). In validate function, i am creating session. when i am going from validate function to facebook function and thr if if i echo session of 'user_id' it is printing.                          --------  but, when i go validate function to client site and then if came back to server/facebook it is not printing